# Syntax for =<(...) in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Using the answer to a question asked on stackoverflow.com, I'm syncing only recent files from a remote host with

```
rsync -av --files-from=<(ssh remoteHost 'find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -exec basename {} \;') remoteHost:pathToRemoteDir .
```

It works fine when executed from the command line (bash), but not when executed from a bash script. I got the following error

```
rsync: failed to open files-from file <(ssh remoteHost 'find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -exec basename {} \;')
```

Being far from expert in bash, I can't figure why the <(...) is not executed but interpreted literally.

Comment: What is the hash-bang of your script, at the first line? Using `#!/bin/bash` is preferred when using bash-specific syntax

Comment: Are you sure your "bash script" is a bash script. Often system shell is not bash

Comment: It seems like `rsync` gets a literal `<(...)` as an argument. Are you sure your script runs in bash (confirm by adding `ps $$` to your script) and executes the exact same command (for instance, there is a difference between `<(...)` and `"<(...)"`)?

Comment: Yes I have `#!/bin/bash` on the 1st line of my script and I'm sure to use /bin/bash on the command line

Comment: If `<(...)` is not replaced, that means that you are not running bash. `-exec basename {} \;` with GNU find I think just `print "%f\n'`. What bash version are you using?

Comment: @LaurentMortier : What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you want is probably:

```sh
rsync -av --files-from=- remoteHost:pathToRemoteDir .  < <(ssh remoteHost 'find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -exec basename {} \;')
```

- `--files-from=-`: When file name is dash, it means the `stdin` stream
- `commands1 < <(commands2)`: means redirect the input of `commands1` as the output of `commands2`.

Basically here with `rsync` it tells to take the files list `--files-from=-` generated by the output of `< <(ssh remoteHost ...)`

Also, you don't need this bash specific redirection, and it can work with a standard piping:

```sh
ssh remoteHost 'find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -exec basename {} \;' | rsync -av --files-from=- remoteHost:pathToRemoteDir .
```

Another remark:

`find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -exec basename {}` is risky and useless. Prefer:

```sh
find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

Finally, if files names contains special characters or newlines, the above syntaxes will break.

So prefer `--from0` with `rsync`:

```sh
ssh remoteHost 'find pathToRemoteDir -mtime -2 -type f -printf "%f\0"' |
  rsync -av --from0 --files-from=- remoteHost:pathToRemoteDir .
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. The command with | works on the command line and in the script, but with `--files-from=-` and `< <(ssh ...)` I got a `syntax error near unexpected token \`<'` in the script (it works on the command line)

Comment: @LaurentMortier That's another hint that it's not actually Bash executing the command.